# Are there Firefox keyboard shortcuts to clear the cache?

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-cache, shortcut, vimperator

With the Firefox web developer toolbar I can select "Miscellaneous → Clear private data → Cache".  Is there a way to do the same with a keyboard shortcut?

*Edit:* I am also using vimperator to drive Firefox with the keyboard; just found out that it's possible using: `:emenu Extra.Web Developer.Miscellaneous.Clear Private Data.Cache`.

Comment: if you set auto-completion, you can simply type
    :emn[tab] cache[tab]
here tab is tab key to jump to the option list displayed. To enable the auto-completiion, type the command:

    :set wildoption=auto

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I think <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> takes out all private data, including the cache. [Heres a link that'll tell you how to set up specific options.](http://kaioa.com/node/82)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it can be set. As most web developers, I need to delete the cookies and auth. session regularly while I want to keep the browser history. Checking and unchecking particular checkboxes each time was really annoying.

Comment: Use Cmd+Shift+Delete on OSX, this will open the same "Clear Recent History" window.  This isn't as good as an immediate clearing of the cache, but it saves a few mouse movements.

Comment: this answer seems to be outdated, the article linked to is still there, but the UI has changed significantly since then and apparently they've moved or taken away this functionality.

Answer (score 27):

You can also **reload and clear cache** for a certain page with

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

on a mac, or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>

on a windows/linux machine.

(these are additions to the *plain* reload shortcuts <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> / <kbd>F5</kbd>)

Comment: carefull, this shortcut also tell the browser to never use the cache for the next session.

i.e. if you add the same image two times, it will be downloaded TWO times :)

ctrl+f5 is dangerous for web developpers ! can lead to strange behaviors that normal users will never see.

Answer (score 3):

I use the web developer add-on to totally disable my cache on my development machine.  That way you never have to worry about clearing your cache.

Comment: "to totally disable my cache on my development machine" - how do you do that? I can't see a button for it in the web developer toolbar.

Comment: @bryan Can you tell us how?

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox is

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

[Source](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard%20shortcuts)

Answer (score 2):

I guess

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>

is not what you want?

Answer (score 2):

For Mac OSX it is

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>

for all browsers (except Safari)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this combination:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>

Comment: Sometimes, that's not good enough. When it doesn't work any more, you have to press CTRL + SHIFT + DELETE and select the options you want. Typically, I just have cache selected and keep everything else.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is go to

```
Tools > Options > Privacy > Show Cookies
```

then just keep the `Show Cookie`s window open.

It stays minimized while on your web page so you just have to hit

```
Maximize > Remove All cookies
```

Answer (score 0):

## <**Firefox**>

Reload the page by emptying cache:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Reload the page by not emptying cache:

<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>